# What does this error mean in Eclipse when debugging?

Tags: java, eclipse

When I try to debug this error is reported:

> ERROR: JDWP Unable to get JNI 1.2
>   environment, jvm->GetEnv() return code
>   = -2 JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_NO_JNI_ENV(183): 
>   [../../../src/share/back/util.c:820]

Comment: Sometime I meet this error when I commented all the code in Main function => Empty main. The solution is put some code in your main function, don't let it to be empty :D

Answer (score 6):

Put
System.exit(0);
as the last statement of main().

Answer (score 4):

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6476706

Its a known bug. That bug has a listing of possible workarounds to your problem.

Answer (score -1):

When you have this kind of error
The TypeSystemHolder.class generated by WSDL2Java is not be placed in your classpath in order to avoid this error.

Please copy TypeSystemHolder.class from "resource/schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans/system/s68C41DB812F52C975439BA10FE4FEE54" folder.

And Paste TypeSystemHolder.class file into your classpath folder (build/classes/schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans/system/s68C41DB812F52C975439BA10FE4FEE54) folder